# Difference in regex result Windows Vs Linux (CentOS)

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I want to capture only the lines that end with two asterisks using the following code:

```
import re
total_lines = 0
processed_lines = 0
regexp = re.compile(r'[*][\s]+[*]$')


for line in open('testfile.txt', 'r'):
    total_lines += 1
    if regexp.search(line):
        print'Line not parsed. Format not defined yet'
    else:
        processed_lines += 1
print "Total lines: {} - Processed lines: {}".format(total_lines, processed_lines)
```

In Windows works fine. But when I used the code in CentOS, the regex does not work. This is the output for `testfile.txt` (file with 40 lines)

Windows `re.__version__ = '2.2.1'`:

```
Line not parsed. Format not defined yet
Line not parsed. Format not defined yet
Line not parsed. Format not defined yet
Line not parsed. Format not defined yet
Line not parsed. Format not defined yet
Total lines: 40 - Processed lines: 35
```

Linux `re.__version__='2.2.1'`:

```
Total lines: 40 - Processed lines: 40
```

Both OS use the same python version. You can found the `testfile.txt` [here](http://txt.do/d6jb8) and [here](http://m.uploadedit.com/bbtc/1503698518189.txt):

Comment: That is strange. Usually, the difference is the line endings. Just FYI: you may omit `[` and `]` around `\s`, `r'[*]\s+[*]$'` is enough.

Comment: Python2 does not open text files in universal newline mode by default. Lines ending in `\r\n` will not match the `$` then. Open the file with mode `rU` to have `\r\n` converted to `\n`, the `$` will match then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the file in universal newline mode `rU` to support I/O on files which have a newline format that is not the native format on the platform in python 2.x, then the $ in your regex will match the EOL.

```
import re
total_lines = 0
processed_lines = 0
regexp = re.compile(r'[*][\s]+[*]$')    

for line in open('testfile.txt', 'rU'):
    total_lines += 1
    if regexp.search(line):
        print'Line not parsed. Format not defined yet'
    else:
        processed_lines += 1
print "Total lines: {} - Processed lines: {}".format(total_lines, processed_lines)
```

[PEP278](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0278/) explained what `rU` stands for:

> In a Python with universal newline support open() the mode parameter
>   can also be "U", meaning "open for input as a text file with universal
>   newline interpretation". Mode "rU" is also allowed, for symmetry with
>   "rb".